# How to resolve (error) ERR unknown command 'service' error in Redis in windows machine?

Tags: laravel, windows, redis, phpredis

I installed Redis-cache in my windows machine,after successfully installed i open reddis-cli in that i run `service redis_6379 status`  it's showing following error

```
(error) ERR unknown command 'service'
```

How to resolve this error and start the redis server ...?

These are the info about my server
`

## Server

redis_version:3.0.504
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:a4f7a6e86f2d60b3
redis_mode:standalone
os:Windows
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:WinSock_IOCP
process_id:22004
run_id:7db1c339b5291dc237372c740f8630fd0c665442
tcp_port:6379
uptime_in_seconds:791
uptime_in_days:0
hz:10
lru_clock:2329164
config_file:C:\Program Files\Redis\redis.windows-service.conf

## Clients

connected_clients:1
client_longest_output_list:0
client_biggest_input_buf:0
blocked_clients:0

## Memory

used_memory:693104
used_memory_human:676.86K
used_memory_rss:655352
used_memory_peak:693104
used_memory_peak_human:676.86K
used_memory_lua:36864
mem_fragmentation_ratio:0.95
mem_allocator:jemalloc-3.6.0

## Persistence

loading:0
rdb_changes_since_last_save:0
rdb_bgsave_in_progress:0
rdb_last_save_time:1629718325
rdb_last_bgsave_status:ok
rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec:-1
rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec:-1
aof_enabled:0
aof_rewrite_in_progress:0
aof_rewrite_scheduled:0
aof_last_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_current_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_last_bgrewrite_status:ok
aof_last_write_status:ok

## Stats

total_connections_received:2
total_commands_processed:2
instantaneous_ops_per_sec:0
total_net_input_bytes:290
total_net_output_bytes:2142
instantaneous_input_kbps:0.00
instantaneous_output_kbps:0.00
rejected_connections:0
sync_full:0
sync_partial_ok:0
sync_partial_err:0
expired_keys:0
evicted_keys:0
keyspace_hits:0
keyspace_misses:0
pubsub_channels:0
pubsub_patterns:0
latest_fork_usec:0
migrate_cached_sockets:0

## Replication

role:master
connected_slaves:0
master_repl_offset:0
repl_backlog_active:0
repl_backlog_size:1048576
repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:0
repl_backlog_histlen:0

## CPU

used_cpu_sys:0.28
used_cpu_user:0.36
used_cpu_sys_children:0.00
used_cpu_user_children:0.00

## Cluster

cluster_enabled:0

## Keyspace

`

Comment: info server, not info service

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear, there's no Redis command called **service**.

If you want to check the status of Redis server, you can run *INFO* command instead. Check thishttps://redis.io/commands) for a list of commands that Redis supports.